# How to display background pictures

Tags: c#, .net, image, background

I simply want to be able to "Insert" background pictures while displaying text in front of it.
I'm new to c# so if possible, keep it simple.

Comment: Insert background pictures to where? A form? A picturebox? A website?

Answer (score 0):

Use the background image property, or add a picture box/control and place a label on top of it, if the label is behind the picture control then move the text label in-front of the picture box

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting `BackGroundImage` property from your code behind if this property is exposed by the `control`.... -

`control.BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile("C:\filename.jpg");`

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you're using the console applications but you cant change the background image on that, if you want to make a program you could try using windows form applications, you can design what you want the user to see and set background images. Change the "BackgroundImage" property, and then import the image you want to use. I'm also new to c# so I know how you feel. Also to impove image quality change it to a bitmap (bmp), its much clearer than a jpeg

Answer (score 0):

To change the background of a form go to the properties of the form and click BackgroundImage

If you want to change it during runtime with code

Make a class called background

```
class Background
{
    public static string background_file;
}
```

This is the class

```
this.BackgroundImage = new Bitmap("file_in_debug_folder");
```

This will change the background on the current form

```
Background.background_file = "$this.BackgroundImage-blue.bmp";
```

This will change the variable in the class to the file location "$this.BackgroundImage-blue.bmp" but this will be changed to the name of your file in the debug folder